# Standard Basis of a $n$ by $m$ matrix in $\mathbb R$

Tags: linear-algebra

Let A be a 2 $\times$ 3 matrix in $\mathbb R$. By definition, would the standard basis of the matrix be the following?

```
[1 0 0]  [0 1 0]   [0 0 1]   [0 0 0]   [0 0 0]   [0 0 0] 
[0 0 0], [0 0 0] , [0 0 0] , [1 0 0] , [0 1 0] , [0 0 1]
```

Thanks.

Comment: If you consider matrices as elements of a vector space, then yes.

Comment: Okay, just making sure I understand the question. Usually, I work with n by n matrices when finding standard basis

Comment: I am not too sure I understand your question. What do you mean by the standard basis of the matrix? Do you mean the standard basis for the vector space of $m\times n$ matrices? Or do you mean the representation of a matrix with respect to the standard basis?

Comment: Yes it would correct.